# Html5 animation

Tags: html

i was searching how to flip pages of e-book with html5 and i get this example

but i was wonder if the book have 300 page i will do with the same way???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="book">
            <canvas id="pageflip-canvas"></canvas>
            <div id="pages">

                <section>
                    <div>
                        <h2>History</h2>
                        <p>Canvas was initially introduced by Apple for use inside their own Mac OS X WebKit component, powering applications like Dashboard widgets and the Safari browser. Later, it was adopted by Gecko browsers and Opera and standardized by the WHATWG on new proposed specifications for next generation web technologies.</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div>

                        <h2>Usage</h2>
                        <p>Canvas consists of a drawable region defined in HTML code with height and width attributes. JavaScript code may access the area through a full set of drawing functions similar to other common 2D APIs, thus allowing for dynamically generated graphics. Some anticipated uses of canvas include building graphs, animations, games, and image composition.</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Reactions</h2>

                        <p>At the time of its introduction the canvas element was met with mixed reactions from the web standards community. There have been arguments against Apple's decision to create a new proprietary element instead of supporting the SVG standard. There are other concerns about syntax e.g. the absence of a namespace.</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Support</h2>
                        <p>The element is currently supported by the latest versions of Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari, and Opera. It is not natively implemented by Internet Explorer (IE) as of version 8, though support is in development for Internet Explorer 9; however, many of the Canvas element's features can be supported in IE, for example by using Google or Mozilla plugins, JavaScript libraries and either Adobe Flash or IE's proprietary VML.</p>

                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="pageflip.js"></script>
    </body>
<html>

 here the jquery



(function() {

    // Dimensions of the whole book
    var BOOK_WIDTH = 830;
    var BOOK_HEIGHT = 260;

    // Dimensions of one page in the book
    var PAGE_WIDTH = 400;
    var PAGE_HEIGHT = 250;

    // Vertical spacing between the top edge of the book and the papers
    var PAGE_Y = ( BOOK_HEIGHT - PAGE_HEIGHT ) / 2;

    // The canvas size equals to the book dimensions + this padding
    var CANVAS_PADDING = 60;

    var page = 0;

    var canvas = document.getElementById( "pageflip-canvas" );
    var context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

    var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    var flips = [];

    var book = document.getElementById( "book" );

    // List of all the page elements in the DOM
    var pages = book.getElementsByTagName( "section" );

    // Organize the depth of our pages and create the flip definitions
    for( var i = 0, len = pages.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        pages[i].style.zIndex = len - i;

        flips.push( {
            // Current progress of the flip (left -1 to right +1)
            progress: 1,
            // The target value towards which progress is always moving
            target: 1,
            // The page DOM element related to this flip
            page: pages[i], 
            // True while the page is being dragged
            dragging: false
        } );
    }

    // Resize the canvas to match the book size
    canvas.width = BOOK_WIDTH + ( CANVAS_PADDING * 2 );
    canvas.height = BOOK_HEIGHT + ( CANVAS_PADDING * 2 );

    // Offset the canvas so that it's padding is evenly spread around the book
    canvas.style.top = -CANVAS_PADDING + "px";
    canvas.style.left = -CANVAS_PADDING + "px";

    // Render the page flip 60 times a second
    setInterval( render, 1000 / 60 );

    document.addEventListener( "mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false );
    document.addEventListener( "mousedown", mouseDownHandler, false );
    document.addEventListener( "mouseup", mouseUpHandler, false );

    function mouseMoveHandler( event ) {
        // Offset mouse position so that the top of the book spine is 0,0
        mouse.x = event.clientX - book.offsetLeft - ( BOOK_WIDTH / 2 );
        mouse.y = event.clientY - book.offsetTop;
    }

    function mouseDownHandler( event ) {
        // Make sure the mouse pointer is inside of the book
        if (Math.abs(mouse.x) < PAGE_WIDTH) {
            if (mouse.x < 0 && page - 1 >= 0) {
                // We are on the left side, drag the previous page
                flips[page - 1].dragging = true;
            }
            else if (mouse.x > 0 && page + 1 < flips.length) {
                // We are on the right side, drag the current page
                flips[page].dragging = true;
            }
        }

        // Prevents the text selection
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function mouseUpHandler( event ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < flips.length; i++ ) {
            // If this flip was being dragged, animate to its destination
            if( flips[i].dragging ) {
                // Figure out which page we should navigate to
                if( mouse.x < 0 ) {
                    flips[i].target = -1;
                    page = Math.min( page + 1, flips.length );
                }
                else {
                    flips[i].target = 1;
                    page = Math.max( page - 1, 0 );
                }
            }

            flips[i].dragging = false;
        }
    }

    function render() {

        // Reset all pixels in the canvas
        context.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

        for( var i = 0, len = flips.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            var flip = flips[i];

            if( flip.dragging ) {
                flip.target = Math.max( Math.min( mouse.x / PAGE_WIDTH, 1 ), -1 );
            }

            // Ease progress towards the target value 
            flip.progress += ( flip.target - flip.progress ) * 0.2;

            // If the flip is being dragged or is somewhere in the middle of the book, render it
            if( flip.dragging || Math.abs( flip.progress ) < 0.997 ) {
                drawFlip( flip );
            }

        }

    }

    function drawFlip( flip ) {
        // Strength of the fold is strongest in the middle of the book
        var strength = 1 - Math.abs( flip.progress );

        // Width of the folded paper
        var foldWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * ( 1 - flip.progress );

        // X position of the folded paper
        var foldX = PAGE_WIDTH * flip.progress + foldWidth;

        // How far the page should outdent vertically due to perspective
        var verticalOutdent = 20 * strength;

        // The maximum width of the left and right side shadows
        var paperShadowWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * Math.max( Math.min( 1 - flip.progress, 0.5 ), 0 );
        var rightShadowWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * Math.max( Math.min( strength, 0.5 ), 0 );
        var leftShadowWidth = ( PAGE_WIDTH * 0.5 ) * Math.max( Math.min( strength, 0.5 ), 0 );


        // Change page element width to match the x position of the fold
        flip.page.style.width = Math.max(foldX, 0) + "px";

        context.save();
        context.translate( CANVAS_PADDING + ( BOOK_WIDTH / 2 ), PAGE_Y + CANVAS_PADDING );


        // Draw a sharp shadow on the left side of the page
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,'+(0.05 * strength)+')';
        context.lineWidth = 30 * strength;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(foldX - foldWidth, -verticalOutdent * 0.5);
        context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT + (verticalOutdent * 0.5));
        context.stroke();


        // Right side drop shadow
        var rightShadowGradient = context.createLinearGradient(foldX, 0, foldX + rightShadowWidth, 0);
        rightShadowGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,'+(strength*0.2)+')');
        rightShadowGradient.addColorStop(0.8, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)');

        context.fillStyle = rightShadowGradient;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(foldX, 0);
        context.lineTo(foldX + rightShadowWidth, 0);
        context.lineTo(foldX + rightShadowWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT);
        context.lineTo(foldX, PAGE_HEIGHT);
        context.fill();


        // Left side drop shadow
        var leftShadowGradient = context.createLinearGradient(foldX - foldWidth - leftShadowWidth, 0, foldX - foldWidth, 0);
        leftShadowGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)');
        leftShadowGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,'+(strength*0.15)+')');

        context.fillStyle = leftShadowGradient;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(foldX - foldWidth - leftShadowWidth, 0);
        context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth, 0);
        context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT);
        context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth - leftShadowWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT);
        context.fill();


        // Gradient applied to the folded paper (highlights & shadows)
        var foldGradient = context.createLinearGradient(foldX - paperShadowWidth, 0, foldX, 0);
        foldGradient.addColorStop(0.35, '#fafafa');
        foldGradient.addColorStop(0.73, '#eeeeee');
        foldGradient.addColorStop(0.9, '#fafafa');
        foldGradient.addColorStop(1.0, '#e2e2e2');

        context.fillStyle = foldGradient;
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)';
        context.lineWidth = 0.5;

        // Draw the folded piece of paper
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(foldX, 0);
        context.lineTo(foldX, PAGE_HEIGHT);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(foldX, PAGE_HEIGHT + (verticalOutdent * 2), foldX - foldWidth, PAGE_HEIGHT + verticalOutdent);
        context.lineTo(foldX - foldWidth, -verticalOutdent);
        context.quadraticCurveTo(foldX, -verticalOutdent * 2, foldX, 0);

        context.fill();
        context.stroke();


        context.restore();
    }

})();
```

the css

```
body, h2, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#book {
    background: url("book.png") no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 830px;
    height: 260px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -400px;
    margin-top: -125px;
}

#pages section {
    background: url("paper.png") no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 415px;
    top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    #pages section>div {
        display: block;
        width: 400px;
        height: 250px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    #pages section p,
    #pages section h2 {
        padding: 3px 35px;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    #pages section h2{
        margin: 15px 0 10px;
    }

#pageflip-canvas {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load the pages dynamically through AJAX in the event handler, this way the user is not forced to download the whole document.

Comment: ok but any one please know any tutorial of make e-book reader like this one http://books.google.com/ebooks/reader?id=MQIwAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&pg=GBS.PA5.w.1.0.0